# CSS Class amcharts-compare-item-div style does not work after addClassNames set true

Tags: amcharts

Changes in style of Compare data item's height in Amchart does not apply to it.

```
    .amcharts-compare-item-div{height:20px}
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the chart elements set their styles inline. In order to have your styles override the inline styles, you have to add `!important` to your rule:

```
.amcharts-compare-item-div{
  height:20px !important;
}
```